# How are asymptotic estimates found in analytic number theory?

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I have begun to study analytic number theory using the book *Analytic Number Theory: Exploring the Anatomy of Integers* by Jean-Marie De Koninck & Florian Luca (I'm only in chapter 2). There are a lot of asymptotic expansions talked about within the book, for example Stirling's formula $$n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$ the prime number theorem$$\pi(x) \sim \frac {x}{\log x}$$ and $$\sum_{p\le x} \frac 1p\sim \log\log x$$ my question is, how are results like these derived? And what methods can be used to prove them?

Comment: The first one can be done with partial summation (on $\log(n!) = \sum_{k=1}^n \log k$), the second is much harder (usually a lot of complex analysis, after showing PNT is equivalent to $\psi(x) \sim x$, where $\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k \leq x} \log p$), and the third is a consequence of a theorem of Mertens that $\sum_{p \leq x} 1/p = \log\log x + M + O(1/\log x)$ for an ugly constant $M$, and that result of Mertens is based on the prime factorization of $N!$ plus partial summation plus the estimate $\psi(x) = O(x)$, which is much weaker than the prime number theorem ($\psi(x) \sim x$).

Comment: If you want to know details on how such results are derived, you should look for books or notes on analytic number theory.  For example, aren't all of these results proved in the very book you are studying?  (On a separate matter, I wonder why you are using a photo of Barry Simon for your image on this site.)

Comment: Lol, I use that for my profile picture. because it's funny, but I'm mostly wondering how results like these are even found in the first place, like I said, I'm only on chapter 2. I would like to do further study into analytic number theory but results like these are all over the place and I'm not too sure how they are found in general.

Comment: The most basic technique used over and over is partial summation, which is a discrete analogue of integration by parts.  Maybe Chapter 1 of Overholt's "A Course in Analytic Number Theory" or Part 1 of Koukoulopoulos's "The Distribution of Prime Numbers" or the first two chapters of Jameson's "The Prime Number Theorem" will be more to your taste than the book you're looking at (even though it too starts off with a discussion of estimation techniques).  These references show additional elementary but useful estimation techniques besides partial summation, such as the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I will be sure to have a look at those!

Comment: Historically, the Prime Number Theorem was conjectured on the basis of numerical data (that's how Gauss was led to propose it). The start of Section 5 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/stirling.pdf indicates the setting in which Stirling's formula was first found (probability, not analytic number theory).

Comment: That's good to know about the prime number theorem. I am interested in analytic number theory for research in the future, so that is reassuring that I won't have to pull stuff like that out of thin air (If I make meaningful contributions, that is)!